# SSIS: Trim some columns w/o doint a Trim in a script component...::::

Tags: ssis, script-component

I have  a table with 48 fields, i am filtering some data and need to use a script component( i need this for 10 of the fields in which i am actually changing the data)  on the other 38 fields I only want to do a trim.  I know i can do this in a script component, but i would rather do it in a more efficient way...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a derived column transformation.  If it's really nothing but a trim, you cna even replace the contents of the field without creatingg a new field in your dataflow.